# how to know whether mysql query result has come from cache?

Tags: mysql, caching

when I am running my query from query window it takes some time, almost 6-7 minutes.
I am running this query again and again for testing. I want to know that result is coming from cache or it is running and generating result, so that i can decide that this much time my query is taking.

I tried 
'flush query cache;' and 'reset query cache;' 
But not sure that is it coming from cache?

My table is myisam.

Comment: try SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE col1 [, coln] FROM table - reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Comment: Note some people here (not me) are experts when it comes to performance. Just sayin'